# How to get information from a website into my tableview row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, youtube-api

The application I'm making is similar to YouTube. It is a TableView that has a custom cell that displays a screenshot of the video, title, duration, and rating. I think I'm able to create this custom cell, my question is what to use to get the information from the website? Thanks for the help, I'm still inexperienced. 
Update: Maybe I didn't word it properly, but I meant to get the video and information from a different web site that isn't YouTube for its videos, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You use [YouTube's API](http://www.youtube.com/dev).